# JSON.net is stripping properties when iterating over them

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json string that I'm parsing to a JObject using `JObject.parse(string)`. When I do this all properties and objects inside that json string are present as evidenced by a `ToString()` method call.  However as soon as I call an IEnumerable method such as

```
var _mapping = JObject.parse(json);
var _json = _mapping.ToString();
// _json == json at this poing other than some formating
var map = _mapping["c1-14.10.16"]["mappings"]["applog"]["properties"];
foreach(JToken v in map) { 
    string s = v.ToString();
    // s != corresponding node string of json
}
```

many properties simply disappear from v and v's children.

Here is a short snippet of json that fails

```
{"c1-14.10.16":{"mappings":{"applog":{"properties":{"error":{"properties":{"error":{"properties":{"data":{"properties":{"DisablePrepareForRethrow":{"type":"string","index_analyzer":"standard"},"HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl":{"type":"string","index_analyzer":"standard"},"HelpLink.EvtID":{"type":"string","index_analyzer":"standard"},"HelpLink.EvtSrc":{"type":"string","index_analyzer":"standard"},"HelpLink.LinkId":{"type":"string","index_analyzer":"standard"},"HelpLink.ProdName":{"type":"string","index_analyzer":"standard"},"Microsoft.ServiceBus":{"type":"string","index_analyzer":"standard"},"length":{"type":"integer"}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

The only property in `"c1-14.10.16".mappings.applog.properties.error.properties.error.properties.data.properties` that is recognized is `length`.  none of the other properties are recognized at all.

What am I doing wrong that makes it strip out the other properties?

Answer (score 1):

The properties are there -- but at a much lower level than your code seems to expect.  You can see this as follows:

```
    public static void TestJsonParse(string json)
    {
        try
        {
            var _mapping = JObject.Parse(json);
            var _json = _mapping.ToString();
            // _json == json at this poing other than some formating

            var map = _mapping["c1-14.10.16"]["mappings"]["applog"]["properties"];
            map.WritePropertiesToConsole();

            Debug.Assert(map.Count() == 1); // No assert because the properties aren't here.

            var subMap = _mapping["c1-14.10.16"]["mappings"]["applog"]["properties"]["error"]["properties"]["error"]["properties"]["data"]["properties"];
            subMap.WritePropertiesToConsole();

            Debug.Assert(subMap.Count() == 8); // no assert - the properties are all here.
            Debug.Assert(_mapping["c1-14.10.16"]["mappings"]["applog"]["properties"]["error"]["properties"]["error"]["properties"]["data"]["properties"]["Microsoft.ServiceBus"]["index_analyzer"].ToString() == "standard"); // no assert
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString());  // No exception, no assert.
        }
    }

    public static void WritePropertiesToConsole(this JToken subMap)
    {
        int iToken = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Tokens for {0}: {1} found", subMap.Path, subMap.Count()));
        foreach (JToken v in subMap)
        {
            string s = v.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Token {0}: {1}", iToken++, s));
        }
    }
```

And here is the console output:

```
Tokens for c1-14.10.16.mappings.applog.properties: 1 found
Token 0: "error": {
  "properties": {
    "error": {
      "properties": {
        "data": {
          "properties": {
            "DisablePrepareForRethrow": {
              "type": "string",
              "index_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl": {
              "type": "string",
              "index_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "HelpLink.EvtID": {
              "type": "string",
              "index_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "HelpLink.EvtSrc": {
              "type": "string",
              "index_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "HelpLink.LinkId": {
              "type": "string",
              "index_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "HelpLink.ProdName": {
              "type": "string",
              "index_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "Microsoft.ServiceBus": {
              "type": "string",
              "index_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "length": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Tokens for c1-14.10.16.mappings.applog.properties.error.properties.error.properties.data.properties: 8 found
Token 0: "DisablePrepareForRethrow": {
  "type": "string",
  "index_analyzer": "standard"
}
Token 1: "HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl": {
  "type": "string",
  "index_analyzer": "standard"
}
Token 2: "HelpLink.EvtID": {
  "type": "string",
  "index_analyzer": "standard"
}
Token 3: "HelpLink.EvtSrc": {
  "type": "string",
  "index_analyzer": "standard"
}
Token 4: "HelpLink.LinkId": {
  "type": "string",
  "index_analyzer": "standard"
}
Token 5: "HelpLink.ProdName": {
  "type": "string",
  "index_analyzer": "standard"
}
Token 6: "Microsoft.ServiceBus": {
  "type": "string",
  "index_analyzer": "standard"
}
Token 7: "length": {
  "type": "integer"
}
```

The properties are there, at exactly the depth specified in the JSON string provided in the question.  So JSON.net isn't stripping anything from the example provided.  You can see the hierarchy clearly using http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/:

[image]

If you change your problem description to be as follows: "given some JSON, how can I recursively find a child property named 'properties' with more than one child property", you can do it like this, adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181298/how-to-do-recursive-descent-of-json-using-json-net):

```
    static IEnumerable<JToken> FindProperties(JToken root)
    {
        return root.WalkNodes().Where(n =>
        {
            var _parent = n.Parent as JProperty;
            if (_parent != null && _parent.Name == "properties")
            {
                if (n.Count() > 1)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    public static IEnumerable<JToken> WalkNodes(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            yield return (JObject)node;

            foreach (JProperty child in node.Children<JProperty>())
            {
                foreach (var childNode in child.Value.WalkNodes())
                    yield return childNode;
            }
        }
        else if (node.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            foreach (JToken child in node.Children())
            {
                foreach (var childNode in child.WalkNodes())
                    yield return childNode;
            }
        }
    }
```

and then, to test it:

```
            var _properties = FindProperties(_mapping);
            var list = _properties.ToArray();
            Debug.Assert(list.Length == 1 && list[0] == subMap); // no assert
```

Comment: unfortunately this isn't answering the question. I have to iterate over the properties, I can't go directly to the properties via indexers as your code example shows.

Look at the ToString() output inside the foreach loop and you should see that some properties have simply disappeared.

Comment: @danatcofo - answer updated.  JSON.net is working correctly with the Json string you provided.  I added a suggestion as to how to recursively find a "properties" node with more than one child property.

Comment: Here is a huge head scratcher....

the same code in a console app finds the properties just fine, but the code inside an MVC3 controller loses the properties....

Comment: @danatcofo - sorry, can't help much with that one.  Maybe there's a problem with the version of Json.Net being used?  Suggest asking a second question to get new pairs of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the json you posted, is invalid.

In an attempt to edit your post so that the json was more formatted, the site I used correctly identified errors in your JSON string.

[Go here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), and paste your JSON there and you'll see the problem:

[image]

Comment: sorry if the json posted has an extra } closing I only posted a snippet containing an offending node and its parentage as the original is very large.  However, THAT is not the problem.  I'll edit the post with corrected json however.

Comment: @danatcofo, it's not just the closing brace :)  See image.

Comment: yah, its actually a node I missed in my edit.  My point still stands however.