# Find a value of all occurrences for a key in a dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, search, dictionary

I have a dictionary with some data and I want to get all the values of each occurrence of specific key name. Is there any predefined method to search for a key in JSON object for all occurrences or need to write user defined method?

Sample data

```
[{"id":"23","name":"sunny","className":"2","class":{"className":"1","class2":{"className":"3","class":{"className":"4"}}}}]
```

this is sample data and I want to get all the values with key 'className'

Comment: Yes. Parse the JSON to anonymous object and use reflection  to recurisvely traverse the object. There is no "built-in" method to do what you want, afaik. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181298/how-to-do-recursive-descent-of-json-using-json-net to get started.

Comment: I am not able to getting your point. Can you give me a small example? @chris Eelmaa

Comment: Do you HAVE a json object, or just a string?

Comment: I think it is not a big deal to convert from string to json object, actually I have string, and I converted it into json object and then to dictionary. If there is possibility with json object only it is much prettier

Comment: A Dictionary allows only one occurrence of a key.