# how to deserialize a json object with different outcomes

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

When I call a web api, I got either a normal object or an error object (If an error occurs) like below;

```
{
    "fault": {
        "correlationId": "ea0323ad-8883-47e6-bcc7-6acf17218b92",
        "faultCode": "ERR-044",
        "faultString": "Authentication policy failed! JWT is not valid!",
        "faultStatusCode": "401",
        "responseFromApi": ""
    }
}
```

Is it possible to deserialize returned json string without knowing it is a normal object or an error object?

Comment: Yes. Which library are you using to deserialize the JSON? Newtonsoft.Json, System.Text.Json, something else?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Do you know about the JToken.Parse() method? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57681402/1043380

Comment: Is the server returning an error status code in the event of an error?  If so, you could check `HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode` as shown in [Using HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync(), how to handle HttpRequestException based on HttpStatusCode without extra SendAsync calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65383186), or call `HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` as shown in [Usage of EnsureSuccessStatusCode and handling of HttpRequestException it throws](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21097730).

Comment: If the server is not returning an error status code in the event of an error, I'd suggest fixing that.  Because checking the status code will be easier than checking the JSON contents.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if it is a json object with key "fault", then choose to deserilize model or error.

```
string jsonString= await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var jsonData = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
if (jsonData.ContainsKey("fault"))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```