# How to convert Json array Keys to lower case?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, json

I am getting a Json Array here is the JSON array

```
[
  {
    "customFieldName": "resolution",
    "fieldName": "Resolution"
  },

  {
    "customFieldName": "lastViewed",
    "fieldName": "Last Viewed"
  },
]
```

I want to convert the Keys to lower case please suggest the solution.
I tried to convert the JSON array to dictionary but not succeeded.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Related: [How to do recursive descent of json using json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181298/how-to-do-recursive-descent-of-json-using-json-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reading all properties inside JsonArray and change the propertyname to lowercase

```
private static void ConvertToLowerCase(JArray jArray)
{
    foreach (var item in jArray.Children())
    {
        foreach (var property in item.Children<JProperty>().ToList())
        {
            property.Replace(new JProperty(property.Name.ToLower(), property.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

call this method by passing the JArray

```
var jArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
ConvertToLowerCase(jArray);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jArray));
```

Output

```
[{"customfieldname":"resolution","fieldname":"Resolution"},{"customfieldname":"lastViewed","fieldname":"Last Viewed"}]
```